# Referencing a nested list item by only its most immediate bullet

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I'd like to be able to reference a nested enumerated list item only by its inner-most identifying character.

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item \label{mylabel} Referenced point.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
...
\ref{mylabel}
```

The `\ref` above gives me something like `1a`, but I want it to give me `a` only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In LaTeX, internal macro `\p@enumN\theenumN` defines the output of a `\ref` command. (ref. `source2e`) The default definitions in standard document classes are (ref. `classes`):

```
\renewcommand\theenumi{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand\theenumii{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
```

You can redefine `\p@enumii` to get what you want:

```
\makeatletter % for internal macros with @
\renewcommand\p@enumii{}
\makeatother
```

---

It seems you are using `enumerate` package to change the label. However, `enumerate` doesn't handle the cross references well. I suggest a more modern package `enumitem` to replace `enumerate`, which can also ease the problem using key-value syntax. For example:

```
% \usepackage{enumitem} % in preamble
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),ref=\alph*]
    \item \label{mylabel} Referenced point.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```